# Import "shortuuid.django_fields" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django-models, django-users

Even after installing django-shortuuidfield, i couldnt import shortuuid or shortuuidfield into my python code. I dont know whats wrong

```
from django.db import models
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField 
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from userauths.models import User


class category(models.Model):
    cid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, length=10, max_length=20, prefix="cat", alphabet="abcdefgh12345")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category')
```

I have tried changing the "from" path like (from . import ShortUUID) or other instances but i keep getting the same error

Comment: It's always helpful if you include the full error message in the question. According to [their readme file](https://github.com/benrobster/django-shortuuidfield?tab=readme-ov-file#usage), the correct include line should be `from shortuuidfield import ShortUUIDField`. Does that work?